# Diagnosing a MacBook that decided to stop powering. (A1342)

Tags: hardware, power, magsafe

I have performed a series of upgrades on my MacBook 2010 (A1342). However, I dropped a screw, opened the device back up and fished it out and then closed it again. But when I then hit the power button, suddenly, nothing happens.

I always unplugged the power plug from the motherboard...but now it wouldn't even seem to accept the MagSafe connection anymore, as the plug does not even light up green nor orange.

So, I would like to know how I could diagnose this situation. I would guess that something is wrong with the power - but what would be a good way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms are not good. The first thing to check on MagSafe issues is to replace that sub assembly since it’s cheap and easy. If you are not able to source that part, you could disconnect the battery and the display to see if you can get the mac to boot as a minimal system (or at least the MagSafe light to work).

Hopefully you don’t need a new logic board, but by disconnecting things that aren’t critical, you should be able to build up a working system assuming each part works.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624

For any Mac that’s not vintage, Consider a flat rate repair at Apple for situations like this. Assuming the internals aren’t mangled badly, they can and will test each part and repair all (including reasonable number of missing screws) for the paid flat rate cost.

Since this is vintage, your best bet is sourcing some cheap donor machines in hopes of getting enough spare parts to validate which item has failed here.

Comment: I would gladly go to an Apple Store - but unfortunately, this model is from 2010, is in fact a 2nd hand one, and pretty much not covered by any kind of warranty. Will they still give it a look?

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix I didn’t research about it being vintage. Buy spare parts cheap from DOA Macs may be your best play.